# Need a browser extension that changes the browser theme based on URL

Tags: web-development, web-browser

Every web developer has been there; you're up late at night trying to develop a new feature. Everything is going fine, or maybe it's not, but then you glance at the URL bar and realize you've been testing on the production site! This happens to me more than I'd like to admit.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a browser extension for FF and/or Chrome that can change the browser theme based on the URL? It's good to always check the URL bar before you start working, but things happen, and it'd be nice to have different themes for different sites to help prevent the above scenario happening!